# How to find a Herbrand-Model to a given set

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have a Language $L=L(\{R,P\},\emptyset,\{c_0,c_1,c_2\})$ where $R$ denotes a two-digit and $P$ a one-digit relation symbol. And I got the set $S=\{\forall x R(x,x), \forall x\exists y \neg R(x,y), \forall x\exists y R(x,y), P(c_0), \forall x\forall y ((P(x) \land R(x,y)) \rightarrow P(y)) \}$.
I have to find a Herbrand-Model $M$ for $L$ such that all elements of $S$ are satisfied.
My problem is that I don't really see what I have to do here since the domain of the Herbrand-Model is simply all closed terms of $L$ (so nothing I can change) and I am not quite sure how to define the interpretaion of $M$ such that it would actually help.
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [Herbrand structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure#Herbrand_structure) $\mathcal M$ for a certain language $\mathcal L$  is a structure made of "syntactical stuff".

Thus, constants of the language plays a double role : they are "names" in the language to denote objects and thy are the "objects" themselves. And so on with "complex" terms buit up from constants and function symbols.

In the FOL language above, with *constant* symbols $c_0,c_1, c_2$, no *function* *symbols* and two *predicate* symbols: $R$ and $P$, we have that the constants must be considered as "objects": the elements of the domain $M$ of the model.

Consider now the set of formulas:

> $S = \{ ∀xR(x,x),∀x∃y¬R(x,y),∀x∃yR(x,y),P(c_0),∀x∀y((P(x)∧R(x,y))→P(y)) \}$

to be satisfied by $\mathcal M$.

Obviously (fourth formula) we need: $P(c_0)$, i.e. we need that $\{ c_0 \} \subseteq P^M$ (the intepretation of the unary predicate symbol $P$).

In order to satisfy the first formula: $∀xR(x,x)$, we need that: $R(c_0,c_0), R(c_1,c_1), R(c_2,c_2)$. Thus: $\{ (c_0,c_0), (c_1,c_1), (c_2,c_2) \} \subseteq R^M$.

This satisfy also the third formula.

For the second one, we need e.g.: $\lnot R(c_0,c_1), \lnot R(c_1,c_2), \lnot R(c_2, c_0)$.

The remaining cases must be handled accordingly, taking into account the fifth formula.

---

In conclusion, we can define $\mathcal M$ with:

> $M = \{ c_0, c_1, c_2\}, P^M = \{ c_0 \}$ and $R^M = \{ (c_0,c_0), (c_1,c_1), (c_2,c_2) \}$

and check that all the formulas in $S$ are satisfied in $\mathcal M$.

Comment: I think i get the idea of the exercise now, but where do I state $R(c_0,c_0),R(c_1,c_1)...$? Is this part of the interpretation?

Comment: @getrektm8 - Consider an interpretation with domain $M = \{ 0,1,2 \}$. In order to satisfy the formula $\forall x \ R(x,x)$, we have that the interpretation of the binary predicate symbol $R$ is the "object" $R^M = \{ (0,0), (1,1), (2,2) \}$.

Comment: So am I right in assuming that if I want to find a Herbrand_Model I actually just need to find fitting $R^M$ and $F^M$? (in this case only $R^M$ because there are no functions)

Comment: @getrektm8 - correct ($R^M$ and also $P^M$).

Comment: I think if $R^M=\{ (c_0,c_0),(c_1,c_1),(c_2,c_2) \}$ and $P^M= \{ c_0 \}$ then all formulas are already satisfied, is that correct? Ok you just confirmed it above :) Thx!

Comment: Now this has nothing to do with my exercise, but this model would still be correct for the set $S'=S \cup \{ \forall x \forall y (R(x,y) \rightarrow R(y,x)) \}$, right?

Comment: @getrektm8 - correct.

Comment: I think I might have found a flaw in your solution, because in my definition of a Herbrand-Model the domain consists of all closed terms, so we have infinitely many in this example: $D= \{ c_0, c_1, c_2, P(c_0), P(P(c_0)), ... \}$ and not simply $\{ c_0, c_1, c_2 \}$

Comment: @getrektm8 - **YOU** have written that "$P$  a one-digit relation symbol"; a relation symbol is not a *function* symbol. If so $P(c_0)$ is a +sentence* and **not** a *term*.

Comment: If $P$ is a function symbol, then the formula $\ldots \to P(y))$ is wrongly written.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, now i had it wrong. $P$ is a relation symbol and therefore $P(c_0)$ is not a term, so your solution was indeed correct

Comment: @getrektm8 - Ok :-). With a *function* symbol (let $f$) you are right in the def of the domain. But in that case we have to change set $S$ of formulas.